# bijection rule (variant): determining if its a bijection

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

In a lecture we are given the following example and I don't understand how if the codomain is $\mathbb{Z}$ this can be a bijection, considering that integers are infinite and in this example the $Ran(f)$ is restricted:

EXAMPLE:
$f:[m..n] \mapsto \mathbb{Z}$ where $f(x) = x+p$.
$f$ is injective and $Ran(f) = [(m+p)..(n+p)]$
By the variant of the bijection rule $|[m..n]| = |[(m+p)..(n+p)]|$.

Thank you!

I understand the $Ranf$, but - is $f$ a bijection?

Comment: Maybe a bijection between $[m,n]$ and $\text {Ran}(f)$...

Answer (score 1):

Any injective function $f:X\to Y$ induces on a natural way the bijective function $g:X\to\mathsf{ran}f$ prescribed by $x\mapsto f(x)$.

This allows the conclusion that $|X|=|\mathsf{ran}f|$ whenever $f$ is injective.

The function $f$ prescribed in your question is not bijective, but the "bijection rule" is applied on the induced bijective function.